# bitwise comparison of IPV6 address

Tags: c++, c, networking, ipv6

I have two IPv6 addresses in string format. I need to compare first 48 bits of these address.

inet_pton() gives me in6_addr.

How so I extract first n bits from these address ?

Comment: The smallest unit of addressable memory is a byte. So you cannot extract n `bits` except when n is a multiple of byte size.

Answer (score 1):

48 bit = 6 Byte
You can just access the bytes of the array in the structure with `[0]`, `[1]`...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To compare, memcmp could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct in6_addr {
unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   /* IPv6 address */
};

char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] //I assumed this has been filled up//
struct in6_addr addr1;

inet_pton(AF_INET6,&str, &addr1)
```

inet_pton will fill up the above struct for us. if you want only the first 6bytes(48bits),

```
unsigned char array[6];
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
array[i] = addr1.s6_addr[i];
```

now you can pass around `array` for your comparison of the subnet.this is how you extract the first 6bytes, I would ideally make a function to compare the first 6btyes of the address instead of doing this every time,it will make your job easier.

this is from unix network programming richard stevens. this is a simple function to compare two ip address.you can directly pass the `sockaddr_xx` structure and the function will do everything for you

```
#ifdef  HAVE_SOCKADDR_DL_STRUCT
#include    <net/if_dl.h>
#endif

int
sock_cmp_addr(const struct sockaddr *sa1, const struct sockaddr *sa2,
         socklen_t salen)
{
if (sa1->sa_family != sa2->sa_family)
    return(-1);

switch (sa1->sa_family) {
case AF_INET: {
    return(memcmp( &((struct sockaddr_in *) sa1)->sin_addr,
                   &((struct sockaddr_in *) sa2)->sin_addr,
                   sizeof(struct in_addr)));
}

#ifdef  IPV6
        case AF_INET6: {
    return(memcmp( &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) sa1)->sin6_addr,
                   &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) sa2)->sin6_addr,
                   sizeof(struct in6_addr)));
}
#endif

#ifdef  AF_UNIX
        case AF_UNIX: {
    return(strcmp( ((struct sockaddr_un *) sa1)->sun_path,
                   ((struct sockaddr_un *) sa2)->sun_path));
}
#endif

#ifdef  HAVE_SOCKADDR_DL_STRUCT
        case AF_LINK: {
    return(-1);     /* no idea what to compare here ? */
}
#endif
}
return (-1);
}
```

you could modify this program to work on a subnet of the first `n` bytes,also its not in string format but some simple modifications will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

As @deviantfan suggested, you need to use the `s6_addr` struct present in the `sockaddr_in6` struct.

```
  unsigned char r=0;
  int i;
  //assuming your addresses are in add1 and addr2 after `inet_pton`.
  for( i=0; i<6;i++ )
       r = (addr1.sin6_addr.s6_addr[i] ^ addr2.sin6_addr.s6_addr[i]) | r ;


  if(!r){
      //Same first 48 bits
  }
  else{
      //Not same
  }
```

Here, I'm XORing each byte of the 6 bytes under concern and ORing all the XORs together. The final result becomes `zero` only when all the 48 bits are same.